# shared service didn't update data to parent component angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, router-outlet

hello i am new in angular 5, i have a shared service provided in appmodule, this is the service

```
import { DetailTransaksi } from '../models/DetailTransaksiModel'
@Injectable()
export class TransaksiService {

  UserTrans:Transaksi;

  constructor() {
    this.UserTrans = new Transaksi();
  }

  getTransaksi(){
    return this.UserTrans;
  }

  addDetail(data:DetailTransaksi){
    this.UserTrans.ListDetail.push(data);
  }

  countDetail(){
    return this.UserTrans.ListDetail.length;
  }

}
```

the child component is within `router-outlet`, then in child component i called `addDetail()` method, but the parent component which is app.component didn't update when i call `countDetail`,  this is my parent component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TransaksiService } from './services/transaksi.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  numPesanan:number;

  constructor(private transService:TransaksiService){
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.numPesanan = this.transService.countDetail();

  }
}
```

Comment: are you using lazy loaded routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, your `ngOnInit()` will run only once and the code `this.numPesanan = this.transService.countDetail();` will only be run once. 
There could be two ways in which you update the parent.

1. Do something on parent so that the countDetail() of the service is run again. For example, upon a button click, call that method of the service.
2. Make the parent listen to the changes in service.

In your service, make a variable:

```
// private makes it to update only within the service.
private listLength = new Subject<Number>();
// public variable will be used to only observe the changes
listLengthObservable = this.listLength.asObservable();

addDetail(data:DetailTransaksi){
    this.UserTrans.ListDetail.push(data);
    this.listLength.next(this.countDetail());
}
```

In the parent component:

```
this.transService.listLengthObservable.subscribe((updatedLength) => {
    this.numPesanan = updatedLength
})
```